# Android studio app not reading pdf, activity opens empty

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have this assigment to make an android studio project due to tomorrow for class.
I am trying to make a pdf open from an assed after logging into the app, but the activity opens empty.Please help.

This is my HomeActivity.java, where the pdf file should open

```
package com.example.proiectdezvoltareaplicatii;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PDFView mPDFView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        mPDFView = (PDFView) findViewById(R.id.pdfView);
        mPDFView.fromAsset("MeditationBook").load();
    }
}
```

This is my activity_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="HomeActivity">
    <com.github.barteksc.pdfviewer.PDFView
    android:id="@+id/pdfView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my gradle.

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

}

android {
This is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.ProiectDezvoltareAplicatii">
    <activity android:name=".HomeActivity"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.proiectdezvoltareaplicatii"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'}
```

This is my LoginActivity.java

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText username, password;
Button btnlogin;
DBHelper DB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin1);
    DB = new DBHelper(this);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(user.equals("")||pass.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                Boolean checkuserpass = DB.checkusernamepassword(user, pass);
                if(checkuserpass==true){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sign in successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}

And this is my activity_login.xml

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText username, password;
Button btnlogin;
DBHelper DB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username1);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password1);
    btnlogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignin1);
    DB = new DBHelper(this);

    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String user = username.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();

            if(user.equals("")||pass.equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Please enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else{
                Boolean checkuserpass = DB.checkusernamepassword(user, pass);
                if(checkuserpass==true){
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sign in successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid Credentials", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

}
Please help me

Comment: StackOverflow is not a place to ask people to do your homework tbh.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run this demo directly:

```
https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer
```

open it with Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

add file extension

```
 mPDFView.fromAsset("MeditationBook.pdf").load();
```

make sure the asset folder is created and file spelling is right